# Underground Electrical Wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

Can you run a 2-2-2-4g AL-MHS 400' electrical wire to a treehouse that will have an 80 amp maximum?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, if you don't mind the voltage drop. Unless you are in Canada and have to mind the voltage drop.

If you are sizing by the 125% rule, an 80A service should have a planned load calculation of 64A or less. A planned load of 80A would need a 100A service and larger wire unless this is the service drop from the meter for the treehouse as a standalone residence (not a subpanel feed from another building.)

64A will be a bit more than [6% voltage drop](https://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html?necmaterial=aluminum&necwiresize=7&necconduit=pvc&necpf=0.99&material=aluminum&wiresize=0.8152&resistance=1.2&resistanceunit=okm&voltage=240&phase=ac&noofconductor=1&distance=400&distanceunit=feet&amperes=64&x=50&y=15&ctype=nec) at 400 feet on 2 AWG Al.

80A would be closer to [8% voltage drop.](https://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html?necmaterial=aluminum&necwiresize=7&necconduit=pvc&necpf=0.85&material=aluminum&wiresize=0.8152&resistance=1.2&resistanceunit=okm&voltage=240&phase=ac&noofconductor=1&distance=400&distanceunit=feet&amperes=80&x=64&y=13&ctype=nec) Slight variance depending on power factor of the load.

If the actual load is lower than either of those, the voltage drop will also be lower.

Comment: Thank you, this helps. I live in NY and this is a sub-panel coming from main house, 200 amp service.